# symfony 5 entities many to many con nuevos campos

Tags: php, symfony

tengo una relacion many to many entre evento y user,
la cosa esta en que necesitaba meter tipoinvitado en la tabla que se genera entre estas dos tablas.
[image: captura sql]

Seguí las instrucciones de : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344073/symfony-manytomany-table-extra-columns/50344465#50344465

y al principio añadia correctamente a los usuarios al evento, y con el nuevo campo de tipoinvitado, pero cuando ya fui a meter la fecha, se estropeo todo. Dando el siguiente error:

```
**An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_evento (user_id, evento_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [6, 17]:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'tipoinvitado' doesn't have a default value**
```

es decir, no detecta que en el controlador le estoy pasando estos dos nuevos campos y da error, logicamente si pongo estos campos a null en la base de datos, no guarda nada, porque los ignora, no se si estoy cometiendo un fallo en el controlador a la hora de hacer el flush con estos dos nuevos datos que meto en la tabla.

controller

```
    public function asignarUsuario(Request $request, Evento $evento, UserHasEvento $userhasevento){
        $user_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
        $users = $user_repo->findAll();    

        $evento = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Evento::class)->findOneById($evento); 
        $form = $this->createForm(AsignarEventoFormType::class, $evento);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $users = $evento->GetUsers();
                foreach($users as $user){
                $user->addEvento($evento);       
                $evento->addUser($user);
                $userhasevento->SetTipoinvitado('normal');
                $userhasevento->setFechainscripcion(new \DateTime('now'));
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($evento);
                $em->persist($userhasevento);
                $em->flush();
            }
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('evento_detalle', ['id' => $evento->getId()]));
 
        }        
        return $this->render('evento/AsignarEvento.html.twig',[
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

entidad

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
 
namespace App\Entity;
 
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user_evento")
*/
class UserHasEvento
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evento", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="evento_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $eventos;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist","remove"}, fetch="LAZY" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tipoinvitado", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $tipoinvitado;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fechainscripcion", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fechainscripcion;    

    public function setTipoinvitado(string $tipoinvitado): self
    {
        $this->tipoinvitado = $tipoinvitado;
 
        return $this;
    }
 
    public function getTipoinvitado(): string
    {
        return $this->tipoinvitado;
    }

    public function getFechainscripcion()
    {
        return $this->fechainscripcion;
    }

    public function setFechainscripcion($fechainscripcion): self
    {
        $this->fechainscripcion = $fechainscripcion;

        return $this;
    }  
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt= new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en la consulta

```
INSERT INTO user_evento (user_id, evento_id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

tienes que agregar valor para `tipoinvitado` o darle un valor por defecto en la tabla de la base de datos

de hecho el error `Field 'tipoinvitado' doesn't have a default value**` lo que dice es que `tipoinvitado` no tiene valor por defecto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ponerle por defecto algo al campo *$tipoinvitado*

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tipoinvitado", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $tipoinvitado = "ALGO POR DEFECTO";
```

Answer (score 0):

noto que no persistes la variable `$user` en tu código, ademas puedes agregar en el **constructor** de tu entidad `UserHasEvento.php` el atributo de `$fechainscripcion` como lo haces con `$createdAt`. Si nos apoyamos en el código que expones la fecha de inscripción siempre va a ser en el momento que se cree el objeto.

```
 if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $users = $evento->GetUsers();
            foreach($users as $user){
            $user->addEvento($evento);       
            $evento->addUser($user);
            $userhasevento->SetTipoinvitado('normal');
            $userhasevento->setFechainscripcion(new \DateTime('now')); // <----- Mover al constructor de la clase
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($evento);
            $em->persist($user); // <----- Incluir el persist de la variable $user
            $em->persist($userhasevento);
            $em->flush();
        }
```